# Send data to Django template via simple_tag

Tags: django, templates, charts, django-templates

My aim is to draw plots with Echart library separate from my main view. Thar is why I created an custom template to send chart data to the template html file. If I do this with render method the data sending is working. I attach my working render view and the custom view (this would be my aim).

**Working view and template:**

*View:*

```
def chart(request):

    data=Test.objects.all()
    data=[i['data'] for i in data]
    attr=[i['attr'] for i in data]
    bar = Bar("Teszt Chart")
    bar.add("Tropo",attr, data, is_stack=True)

    bar_chart = bar
    context = dict(
        myechart=bar_chart.render_embed(),
        host=DEFAULT_HOST,
        script_list=bar_chart.get_js_dependencies()
    )
    return render(request, 'test/chart.html', context)
```

*Template*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test chart</title>
        {% for jsfile_name in script_list %}
    <script src="{{host}}/{{jsfile_name}}.js"></script>
    {% endfor %}
</head>

<body>
  {{myechart|safe}}
</body>

</html>
```

**My custom template: (not working)**

*View:*

register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)

```
def chart():
    data=Test.objects.all()

    data=[i['data'] for i in data]
    attr=[i['attr'] for i in data]
    bar = Bar("Teszt Chart")
    bar.add("Tropo",attr, data, is_stack=True)
    bar_chart = bar

    myechart=bar_chart.render_embed()
    host=DEFAULT_HOST
    script_list=bar_chart.get_js_dependencies()

     data={
    'myechart':myechart,
    'host':host,
    'script_list': script_list,
    }

    return data
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{%load chart%}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proudly presented by PycCharts</title>
    {% for  i in chart %}
    <script src="{{i.host}}/{{i.jsfile_name}}.js"></script>
    {% endfor %}
</head>

<body>

  {%for i in chart%}
        {{i.myechart}}
  {%endfor%}
</body>

</html>
```

My main question: How can I pass the data from simple_tag view? If I use this :`{% chart %}` my data is appear but I want to show the separately from each other. Thank you in advance for your answer!

**My traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.1.190:800/chart/

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
['monitor.apps.MonitorConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mathfilters',
 'django_echarts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /gnss_monitor/scr/monitor/templates/monitor/chart.html, error at line 10
   list index out of range
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : <html>
   3 : {%load chart%}
   4 : <head>
   5 :     <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :     <title>Proudly presented by PycCharts</title>
   7 : </head>
   8 : 
   9 : <body>
   10 :  {% chart as variable %} 
   11 : {{ variable.myechart }}
   12 : 
   13 : 
   14 : </body>
   15 : 
   16 : </html>
   17 : 

Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/gnss_monitor/scr/monitor/views.py" in test
  66.   return render(request,'monitor/chart.html')

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  15.             return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in get_template
  34.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/engine.py" in get_template
  144.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  126.                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py" in get_template
  30.                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  160.         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_nodelist
  198.             return parser.parse()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  483.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  481.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/library.py" in compile_func
  121.                     kwonly, kwonly_defaults, takes_context, function_name,

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/library.py" in parse_bits
  245.         if params[0] == 'context':

Exception Type: IndexError at /chart/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign tag's result to template varialbe with `as` syntax and then access to each element of varible through `.`:

```
{% chart as variable %}
{{ variable.myechart }}
{{ variable.host }}
{{ variable.script_list }}
```

Comment: If I use it I got  list index out of range error message. I forgot to mention that I use Django 2.0

Comment: @bummm26 Add full trace ack

Comment: I add to my question my traceback.

Comment: @bummm26 Since you are using `takes_context` your custom tag should take at least one argument: `context`: `def chart(context)`. Or you can just remove `takes_context`.